# How can i add "shortcuts" in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, shortcuts

How can i add shortcuts like 'rst' for restarting the tomcat in the terminal?

Comment: Voting to migrate on superuser.com

Comment: Voting to migrate to unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @AndrewJackson: Of course you did, at 1 rep.

Answer (score 9):

Depends on your desktop environment or how you want to access it.

**Do you want a nice icon on your desktop?**

Create an application icon (which is the closest equivalent to a MS Windows Shortcut): KDE: Perform a right click in a Folder View and select 'Create new -> Link to Application...'

**Do you want it to be available from the bash only?**

Create an alias in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile:

```
alias rst='service tomcat restart'     # Ubuntu with upstart
alias rst='/etc/init.d/tomcat restart' # Other distributions w/o upstart
```

However note that it will not be available from shell scripts in this case.

**Do you want to make it available just like an executable file to bash and shell scripts?**

Create a symbolic link in a folder in the PATH. I recommend to create a ~/bin folder, where you can add your personal scripts and links and add this folder to your path in the .bashrc:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```

Note that some applications might fail to start as the working directory is not set properly. In this case create a shell script in your ~/bin folder that changes to the respective folder first:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /opt/myAppHomeDirectory
./myapp "$@"
```

Oh, and don't forget to make this script executable of course using chmod.

Comment: @Yaba: nice breakdown. Suggested improvements: `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"` so that it doesn't break if there is a space in `$PATH`; in the script, change `./myapp` to `./myapp "$@"` so that you can still pass command line arguments to the script.

Comment: You are right. I've edited my post.

Just one comment: Spaces in directory names on Unix systems are evil. Sooner or later you will find a script that gets into trouble with it.

Answer (score 5):

Multiple possibilities:

1. create [shell scripts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script) of that name and put them somewhere on the `PATH` (or modify the `PATH`) to reference the directory containing those scripts
2. create [aliases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(command)) in your shells .rc file (`.bashrc` for bash)